# Bias point analysis

Tags: bias, pspice

I am trying to simulate an error amplifier in pspice. In the simulation settings, I came across bias point analysis.

I could not understand the meaning of bias point and what is the meaning of bias point analysis?

For which analysis should I use bias point analysis?

Comment: This is very basic stuff, I suggest reading the Pspice manual or a book about using a circuit simulator. You do know what a bias point is I hope ? If not, study it in a book about electronics !

Comment: Plenty of material available with a Google search. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

During "Bias point analysis" the program computes the starting conditions for all other analyses (AC and TRAN). That means: The program uses all DC sources and neglects all reactive components which are effectiv for ac only (capacitors and inductors). For example: In case of a simple BJT amplifier stage, all dc voltages (Vbe, Vce) and dc currents (Ic, Ie, Ib) are calculated. These data (operating point) are necessary either to perform a small-signal anylysis (AC) or as a starting point for an analysis in the time domain (TRAN).

Comment: TLDR: this is a somewhat unfortunate name in Pspice for DC analysis: https://books.google.com/books?id=SK0UX3GdPO8C&pg=SA1-PA5 It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with transistors.

Comment: I'm not exactly a Pspice expert, but it probably just does what the ".op" (DC Operating Point) directive does in plain SPICE.